# Capture Kinect event to a scatterViewItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, kinect, pixelsense

I'm attempting to adapt a MSSurface application to allow use of a Kinect.  Using the code4fun libraries, I'm able to generate an event from the Kinect when a user puts their hand towards the screen, but what I'm missing is how to trigger a ScatterViewItem's touch or click event to grab item, and then release it once finished moving.  from the kinect skeleton model I can get adjusted x/y co-ordinates which i could apply if I can trap the right events in the ScatterViewItem..  And code suggestions would be appreciated...

regards,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to move the item, the easiest thing is to set the ScatterViewItem's Center property to the translated x/y coordinates. You can then control when the item is 'grabbed' fairly easily using whatever conditions you want.

If you are also after pinch/zoom, you'll have to do some playing around. Since the Kinect doesn't have the resolution to detect the fingers pinching and zooming, you could implement this by mapping the Z coordinate of the hand to preset sizes on the grabbed ScatterViewItem.